# Debian preseed in initrd not running?

Tags: debian, iso, preseed

I'm trying to make a headless installer of Debian so I can connect through SSH to install it on a system without peripherals. I have this setup but the preseed does not seem to be executed.

I followed the steps outlined in the [docs](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Preseed/EditIso#Adding_a_Preseed_File_to_the_Initrd).

```
xorriso -as mkisofs -r -V 'Debian 12.4.0 amd64 n' -o ../.././debian-12.4.0-amd64-netinst-headless.iso -J -joliet-long -cache-inodes -isohybrid-mbr ../isohdpfx.bin -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -no-emul-boot -eltorito-alt-boot -e boot/grub/efi.img -no-emul-boot -isohybrid-gpt-basdat -isohybrid-apm-hfsplus ./
```

I then flashed the image with:

```
dd bs=4M if=debian-12.4.0-amd64-netinst-headless.iso of=/dev/sdh status=progress oflag=sync
```

The image boots correctly but the ssh doesn't start and nothing other than the installation choice (graphical, console, expert etc.) appears on screen (idk if its even supposed to).

My `preseed.cfg`: [DebianInstaller/NetworkConsole](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/NetworkConsole)

```
d-i debian-installer/locale string en_US.UTF-8
d-i debian-installer/language string en
d-i debian-installer/country string PL
d-i console-keymaps-at/keymap select us
d-i keyboard-configuration/xkb-keymap select us
d-i netcfg/choose_interface select auto

d-i netcfg/get_hostname string headless
d-i netcfg/get_domain string local
d-i hw-detect/load_firmware boolean true
d-i anna/choose_modules string network-console
d-i preseed/early_command string anna-install network-console
d-i network-console/start select continue
d-i network-console/password password [password]
d-i network-console/password-again password [password]
d-i netcfg/wireless_show_essids select manual
d-i netcfg/wireless_essid string [ssid]
d-i netcfg/wireless_essid_again string [ssid]
d-i netcfg/wireless_security_type select wpa
d-i netcfg/wireless_wpa string [password]
```